# How to find a slater named Patrick M Golden in 1870 records?

Tags: united-states, occupation, 1870s

According to [this image](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:VRQD-2FL) from NARA microfilm publication M233, published as part of *United States Registers of Enlistments in the U.S. Army, 1798-1914*, Irish immigrant Patrick Golden worked as a slater before enlisting in Boston on January 22, 1872, in Company D of the 7th Regiment. (His last name appears as "Goldan" in the enlistment record, but other documents give his name at "Patrick M. Golden".)

According to FamilySearch, there are 7 1870 census records for Irishmen named Patrick Golden/Goldan born 1848-1850. The occupations and locations are:

- [Painter (house), Massachusetts](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MD3Y-MLR)
- [Carpenter, New Jersey](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MNDV-77T)
- [Carpenter, New York, New York](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M8NV-WTR)
- [Laborer, Westchester, New York](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M82W-NRH)
- [Laborer, New York, New York](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M867-NG3)
- [Carpenter, New York, New York](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:M86J-ZJN)
- [Laborer, Philadelphia](https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MZT9-BB7)

There could be many reasons I don't see a slater:

- He may not have been working as a slater in 1870.
- A more general term, such as "laborer" might have been used on the census.
- He may not have been counted in the 1870 census.
- I may have needed to search a broader range of ages.
- His last name may have been spelled differently.

He died in 1876, so later census records would not be helpful. (See [WikiTree entry](https://www.wikitree.com/wiki/Golden-2320).)

I have not found any census record indices that allow searching by occupation.

Is there anywhere I can search for a person named Patrick Golden working as a slater in the early 1870s, possibly near Massachusetts?

Comment: Do you know what his relationship might have been to this [Patrick Golden](https://www.findagrave.com/memorial/2589704/patrick-golden), who was also an Indian fighter, and also from the same county in Ireland, and died between 1870 and 1880 censuses(and might be one of your other census entries)?

Comment: @user2448131 Great question, especially because both are from County Sligo (something I didn't mention above). I wish I knew the answer.

Comment: Also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Golden). If this is an uncle, then perhaps locating him might locate your Patrick.